# When I start one AnimationDrawable in the ListView item, some other AnimationDrawable starts

Tags: android, listview, adapter, animationdrawable, android-viewholder

In each item of the ListView, there is an ImageView. I have set it's ImageDrawable with an AnimationDrawable. When the ResultReceiver receives a result, the AnimationDrawable starts or stop.

Here is my code:

```
public class PicassoListNearbyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private PlaySoundServiceReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    public View getView ( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if ( convertView == null ) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate ( R.layout.nearby_fragment_info_listitem_layout, parent, false );
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder ();
            viewHolder.infoSound = ( ImageView ) convertView.findViewById ( R.id.infoSound );
            convertView.setTag ( viewHolder );
        } else {
            viewHolder = ( ViewHolder ) convertView.getTag ();

        }

        viewHolder.infoSound.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {

            @Override
            public void onClick ( View v ) {

                boolean isServiceRun = ServiceUtils.isServiceRun ( context, "com.***.service.PlaySoundService" );
                if ( isServiceRun ) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent ( "android.intent.action.pauseRecordIntent" );
                    intent.putExtra ( "status", "pause" );
                    activity.sendBroadcast ( intent );
                } else {
                    receiver.setListener ( new PlaySoundServiceReceiver.Listener () {

                        @Override
                        public void onReceiveResult ( int resultCode, Bundle resultData ) {

                            AnimationDrawable animationDrawable;
                            switch ( resultCode ) {
                                case 1024:
                                    viewHolder.infoSound.setImageResource(R.drawable.animation1);
                                    try {
                                        viewHolder.infoSound.setImageDrawable ( activity.getResources ().getDrawable ( R.drawable.animation1 ) );
                                        animationDrawable = ( AnimationDrawable ) viewHolder.infoSound.getDrawable ();
                                        animationDrawable.start ();
                                    } catch ( ClassCastException e ) {
                                        e.printStackTrace ();
                                    }

                                    break;

                                case 1026:
                                    viewHolder.infoSoundProgress.setVisibility ( View.GONE );
                                    try {
                                        animationDrawable = ( AnimationDrawable ) viewHolder.infoSound.getDrawable ();
                                        animationDrawable.stop ();
                                    } catch ( ClassCastException e ) {
                                        e.printStackTrace ();
                                    }

                                    viewHolder.infoSound.setImageDrawable ( activity.getResources ().getDrawable ( R.drawable.yi_nearby_recordbutton ) );
                                    boolean isServiceRun = ServiceUtils.isServiceRun ( context, "com.***.service.PlaySoundService" );
                                    if ( isServiceRun ) {
                                        activity.unbindService ( conn );
                                    }

                                    break;

                            }
                        }
                    } );

                    Intent intent = new Intent ( activity, PlaySoundService.class );
                    intent.setAction ( ACTION_PLAY );
                    intent.putExtra ( EXTRA_SOUND_URL, ( String ) list.get ( position ).get ( "commoditySound" ) );
                    intent.putExtra ( "rec", receiver );
                    activity.bindService ( intent, conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE );

                }

            }
        } );
    } 
}
```

**Here's my problem:**

When one AnimationDrawable starts, some other AnimationDrawables in other list item starts too, but not all.

Thanks for any help / advice or experiences shared.